# Branch deploys with old commit

Tags: github, teamcity

I have two branches in Github. Master and CoolFeature. 
When i check CoolFeature in Github i see that it is even with Master.

When i deploy through Team City the Master branch somehow i get a commit from the Master branch that is five commits behind. I can see it in Team City by checking the SHA1. Is there some feature i have missed?

When i deploy the CoolFeature branch then the latest changes works cause CoolFeature deploys the latest commit.

Edit:

When i checkout the master branch i get this message:

```
> git checkout origin/master
Note: checking out 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at e86824af5...
```

The SHA1 hash refered e86824af5... IS the latest commit. And this is the one i want to be deployed. But TeamCity deploys a commit that is five commits behind this one. I can see it in the log comparing the SH1 hash ids.